# Проблема при настройке managed switch-а

Tags: lan, коммутатор

Настраиваю managed switch (Tenda TEG5312F). ОС Windows 10 Pro. Задача через браузер зайти в пользовательский веб-интерфейс (http://192.168.0.1/) и внести некоторые изменения.

Для этого, если следовать инструкции, требуется на рабочей станции вручную назначить IPv4-адрес в формате 192.168.0.x (x от 2 до 254) и маску подсети 255.255.255.0. После подобных действий я успешно логинюсь в web UI switch-а и все (вроде) работает.

Но тогда, не знаю как выразиться квалифицированно...пропадает интернет! Если IP получается автоматически (via DHCP), то соответственно интернет работает, а вот интерфейс управления switch-ом нет... Т.е. приходится буквально выбирать что-то одно. Такая вот дилема.

В каком направлении копать? Админ я очень начинающий, поэтому не судите строго.